# How to check for existence of a row in mysql without using INSERT IGNORE?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I currently use this query to update listings in my database from my php app:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO listings (title, description) VALUES ('$title','$description')";
```

This listings table has a 'postid' column as it's primary key that auto increments.

I don't want to do an INSERT IGNORE and have it check postid.  Instead, I'd like to keep the table structure the same and check to see if $title exists.. and not insert if it does.

Will php/mysql allow me to somehow run a:

```
If ($title does not exist) {
$query = "INSERT INTO listings (title, description) VALUES ('$title','$description')";
}
```

If so, how would I write that?

Comment: "I don't want" --- any *real reason* to not want a good solution?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: Well the problem is that I need to keep the table structure as is for anyone who submits a listing.  It works well how it's written. For my script though, I'm trying to backdoor rss feeds into the database, so the PostId will never suffice.  If I grab an rss feed 3X in a row, it will populate my db with the same rss items and simply auto increment the postid.  Therefore.. for the "back door" items, I need to key off of the title.  I also tried creating a guid field, since that can be found in the rss feed, but since my postid is the primary key, I can't use this to be my unique field either.

Comment: it's amazon rss feeds.. so if the occasional title isn't unique and doesn't get inserted.. no biggie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the dollowing:

Query your database to see if there is already any list with the given title and if the count query returns 0, execute your insert statement:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT count(*) as total from listings where title="$title"');

$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);    

if($result['total'] == 0){
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO listings (title, description) VALUES ('$title','$description')");
}
```

But I strongly suggest you to do not manipulate your database this way. Better to use an ORM or a database class instead of putting your SQL statements all over the place.

Good luck.

Comment: that did it!  thank you so much!  I know it seems an odd way to do this, but I'm just inserting the occasional 20 rss items via cron once a day.. so this solution will work well for me.  Many many many thanks for your solution!  I spent all night trying to figure it out so I am pleased!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO listings (title, description) VALUES ('$title','$description')
FROM dual WHERE not exists (SELECT title FROM listings WHERE title = '$title');
```

Or you can do like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE listings SET description = '$description' WHERE title ='$title';");        
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO listings (title, description) VALUES ('$title','$description');");
}
```

Comment: tried them both but neither worked.  thank you for trying though!

Comment: The first example should definitely work. Make sure you are using the correct quotes in the correct locations, though (since the example Hatake posted doesn't have the PHP surrounding it)

 http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php

Comment: I think that link you gave is for mssql and not mysql.  Maybe?  I tried again but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'll try some more though!